# First click event not working JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, navigation

I am having an issue I'm not sure how to work out, I have a "Expand Navbar" button/link that is supposed to, when clicked bring down a navigation menu from the top of the window. Now this does work but only after you click the button the second time.

After reading other posts:
I have tried to invert the if/else statement, but this didn't work I have also tried to check for nulls but making the if statement read:

```
if(showNav.style.top === "")
```

But this also didn't work. Some posts say, regarding a similar issue that you should move the JS file into the head of the HTML but this doesn't seem right to me?

Please see my code below:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/main.css">
  <title>Navbar Dropdown Anim</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="navbar__container">
    <div class="navbar__container__logo"><a href="" class="navbar__container__logo__link">
        <h1>Logo</h1>
      </a></div>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <ul class="navbar__list">
        <li class="navbar__list__item"><a href="" class="navbar__list__item__link">Home</a></li>
        <li class="navbar__list__item"><a href="" class="navbar__list__item__link">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="navbar__list__item"><a href="" class="navbar__list__item__link">Services</a></li>
        <li class="navbar__list__item"><a href="" class="navbar__list__item__link">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <h2><a id="btn" href="#">Expand Navbar</a></h2>

  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}

.navbar__container {
  position: relative;
  top: -100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 55px 50px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 12px 5px #777;
  background: #333;
  transition: all .4s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;

  &__logo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }

  &__logo__link {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color:  #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;

    &__list {
      display: flex;

      &__item {
        margin-right: 15px;
        list-style: none;

      }

      &__item__link {
        color:  #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

JS:

```
btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
showNav = document.querySelector('.navbar__container');


btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('Button Clicked')
  if(showNav.style.top === "-100%") {
    showNav.style.top = "0";
  } else {
    showNav.style.top = "-100%"
  }
})
```

I'm sure there is a lot of better ways to do this and also I apologise in advance if I have breached any posting etiquettes, would really appreciate some help to understand where I am going wrong here.

Many Thanks

Comment: Consider using `getComputedStyle` instead?

Comment: Also, consider not using a style to track the open state of the nav. Use a separate variable instead.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yep tried that maybe I am using it incorrectly i don't know. How would this be used properly? I had used it int the if statement between the parenthesis?

Comment: This sort of stuff is much easier with CSS classes

Answer (score 0):

Probably, when you inverted the condition, you have compared `style.top` to `"0"` value. But the value is not equal to just zero, but rather zero units of something (pixels by default) `"0px"`. You can set percentage to be sure what you compare:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if(showNav.style.top === "0%") {
        showNav.style.top = "-100%";
    } else {
        showNav.style.top = "0%";
    }
})
```

Or you can do it with more CSS:

```
.navbar__container { top: -100%; }
.navbar__container.opened { top: 0%; }
```

and just a bit of JS:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    showNav.classList.toggle('opened');
});
```

Comment: ok this worked perfectly. I maybe screwed up the units yes. However, is this a viable solution is there a better way to implement such a feature of a drop down navbar? how would you do it or consider doing it?

Comment: Usually, it's done via styles:

.navbar__container { top: -100%; }
.navbar__container.opened { top: 0%; }

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  showNav.classList.toggle('opened');
});

Comment: I've completed the comment above, please check it